# How can I give a variable on Python to iFrame tag?

Tags: javascript, python, html, iframe, folium

My main goal is to show various videos on the popup on Foluim.

I would like to use the variable "soundURL" which is created on Python in the src of iframe.

How can I give the variable which was made in Python on HTML tag?

```
for _, sound in sounds.iterrows():
  #soundURL=sound["YouTube URL"].replace('https://youtu.be/', '')
  test = folium.Html('''<html>
<h1>環境音</h1>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/' > </iframe>
</body>
</html>
  ''', script=True)
  popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
  folium.Marker(
  location = [sound["Latitude"], sound["Longtitude"]],
  popup = popup
).add_to(my_map)

my_map
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
f'''<html>
<h1>環境音</h1>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src='{soundURL}' > </iframe>
</body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: It didn't work...